# Comparing Oracle version in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to create a bash script to install an application that requires Oracle 11g client.

How can I read in the version info within the bash script?

sqlplus when run in Putty spits out the answer. However, when I use sqlplus in the bash script it wants to connect to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran `sqlplus user/password@sid` on a 64-bit Red Hat server. This was on stdout:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Wed Jun 24 17:27:57 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

Note that it gives the version of Oracle that `sqlplus` belongs to, and the version that's running the actual database.

Just to get the version of Oracle that `sqlplus` belongs to you could do this:

```
sqlplus /NOLOG < /dev/null | grep Release | cut -d' ' -f3
```

Comment: @triplus - Glad I could help. The custom is to upvote good answers, and mark the best or correct answer.